# why this list did not become a list of dictionaries [python]?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

i copied a dictionary to a list but when i print the list it gives the keys without values.
values did not copied to the list

```
Taqueria = {
    "Baja Taco": 4.25,
    "Burrito": 7.50,
    "Bowl": 8.50,
    "Nachos": 11.00,
    "Quesadilla": 8.50,
    "Super Burrito": 8.50,
    "Super Quesadilla": 9.50,
    "Taco": 3.00,
    "Tortilla Salad": 8.00
}
lst = []
for i in Taqueria:
    lst.append(i)
    
print(lst)
```

i expected to get something like this

```
[{"Baja Taco": 4.25},{"Burrito": 7.50},{"Bowl": 8.50},{"Nachos": 11.00},{"Quesadilla": 8.50},{"Super Burrito": 8.50},{"Super Burrito": 8.50},{"Taco": 3.00},{"Tortilla Salad": 8.00}]
```

edit:
it is happened for me with this code

```
import csv
import requests

download = requests.get(
    "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/saso1111/ddd/main/Book1.csv"
)
decoded_content = download.content.decode("utf-8")
file = decoded_content.splitlines()
reader = csv.DictReader(file)      

book = []

for i in reader:
    book.append(i)

print(book)
```

and the result was like this:

```
[{'state': 'Washington', 'fips': '53'}, {'state': 'Illinois', 'fips': '17'}, {'state': 'California', 'fips': '6'}]
```

also photo for the code and the result
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mRSWo.png)

as you can see the result was a list of dictionaries

Comment: At the moment you should see a list of the keys. to get a list of the individual key/values pairs check out `.items()`. A list of key value pair tuples can be turned into a dictionary via `dict()`

Comment: **why** did you expect `i` would be `{"Baja Taco": 4.25}`? What result are you actually trying to get? What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Iterating over a dictionary iterates over the keys. To iterate over both keys and values, use `Taqueria.items()`. This returns tuples, you'll need to turn those into dictionaries.

```
lst = [{key: value} for key, value in Taqueria.items()]
```

For your CSV file you don't need to use `.items()` because `csv.DictReader` returns a sequence of dictionaries. Just access the appropriate keys:

```
book = [{row['state']: row['fips']} for row in reader]
```

Comment: i give more information in the question, can you please review again

Comment: `csv.DictReader` returns a sequence of dictionaries, not a single dictionary. Your code is for a completely different kind of input.

Comment: I've added the solution for `reader`.